# Use Group-By at a higher level than Max command in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max

I am doing a query where I need to strip out some lower-level results using the Max command in SQL Server.  How can I then make a higher level Group By statement?  I know I can use a temp table for this.  I expect high volume and want to avoid creating and destroying the temp table for performance purposes.

```
SELECT k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name, max(k.Value_Percentage) as Percentage 
FROM Key_Word k
LEFT JOIN Phrase p 
    ON p.Result_ID = k.Result_ID 
    AND p.Key_Name = k.Key_Name 
    AND k.Phrase_Flag = 1
    AND  @fulltextsearch LIKE '%' + p.phrase + '%'
WHERE k.Key_Word IN 
    ('estimated', 'flow', 'cash', 'approximate', 'brian', 'go', 'store') 
    AND (k.Phrase_Flag = 0 OR p.Phrase IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name
ORDER BY k.Result_ID ASC;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) ?:

```
SELECT k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name, max(k.Value_Percentage) as Percentage 
FROM Key_Word k
LEFT JOIN Phrase p 
ON p.Result_ID = k.Result_ID 
AND p.Key_Name = k.Key_Name 
AND k.Phrase_Flag = 1
AND  @fulltextsearch LIKE '%' + p.phrase + '%'
WHERE k.Key_Word IN 
('estimated', 'flow', 'cash', 'approximate', 'brian', 'go', 'store') 
AND (k.Phrase_Flag = 0 OR p.Phrase IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name
HAVING max(k.Value_Percentage) > 10
```

Or if you need to you want to show `max(k.Value_Percentage)` per Result_ID , you can
use `WITH ROLLUP`

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what principle you have in mind when talking about ‘stripping out’ lower-level results. If you mean to filter the results based on a certain *value* then [a1ex07's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667704/297408) seems the way to go.

But if you meant filtering them according to the *rankings* of the MAX values returned (i.e. show only the rows with the topmost MAX value or, maybe, with the top 3 values), then here's what you could do:

1. Use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` (`1` because it works reliably only for the topmost MAX):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name, MAX(k.Value_Percentage) as Percentage 
     FROM Key_Word k
     LEFT JOIN Phrase p 
         ON p.Result_ID = k.Result_ID 
         AND p.Key_Name = k.Key_Name 
         AND k.Phrase_Flag = 1
         AND  @fulltextsearch LIKE '%' + p.phrase + '%'
     WHERE k.Key_Word IN 
         ('estimated', 'flow', 'cash', 'approximate', 'brian', 'go', 'store') 
         AND (k.Phrase_Flag = 0 OR p.Phrase IS NOT NULL)
     GROUP BY k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name
     ORDER BY MAX(k.Value_Percentage) DESC
   ) s
   ORDER BY Result_ID ASC;
   ```
2. Use the `DENSE_RANK()` function (requires SQL Server 2005 or later version):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(k.Value_Percentage)) AS ranking
       k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name, MAX(k.Value_Percentage) as Percentage 
     FROM Key_Word k
     LEFT JOIN Phrase p 
         ON p.Result_ID = k.Result_ID 
         AND p.Key_Name = k.Key_Name 
         AND k.Phrase_Flag = 1
         AND  @fulltextsearch LIKE '%' + p.phrase + '%'
     WHERE k.Key_Word IN 
         ('estimated', 'flow', 'cash', 'approximate', 'brian', 'go', 'store') 
         AND (k.Phrase_Flag = 0 OR p.Phrase IS NOT NULL)
     GROUP BY k.Result_ID, k.Key_Name
   ) s
   WHERE ranking <= n
   ORDER BY Result_ID ASC;
   ```